# Borceux - Snake Lemma Question

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Below is the statement of the snake lemma from Borceux. My question is which squares are (1) and (2) referring to?

[image]

Comment: Aren't the columns assumed to be exact as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He means the two central squares, $\nu\theta=\lambda\zeta$ and $\xi\lambda=\mu\nu$.

Comment: Indeed, because the other squares are constructed as part of the proof/construction.

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes. One can add that the upper row is induced by the second row, and the last row by the third row.